# Where to get some generic ruleset for the firewall of a domain controller?

Tags: windows-server-2008, firewall, domain-controller, backup-restoration

I've blown up the firewall rules on a domain controller (DC). Since there are no restore points in Windows 2008 and restoring everything from a full backup is not a solution in this case, how do I:

- Either get the rules back from a full backup, without doing a full restore,
- Or get a document explaining most firewall rules used by Windows servers (including DC, servers with DNS role, or acting as web servers, etc.), letting me to spend more time on this, but knowing precisely what's opened in the firewall. Where can I find such documentation?

I am aware of the fact that I can just install a fresh copy of a DC on a virtual machine, export the policy, and import it to the existent DC. I want to avoid that, since the rules were changed a lot since the original installation of the DC.

Note that Restore Default option results in a "Could not restore the default settings (error: 3)" error, so it is not an option.

Comment: What did you do to break it?

Comment: @Dan: installed Trojan.Win64/Sirefef.W. Quite effective if you want to break things.

Comment: Wipe your DC, dude. It's not worth bothering with.